# Struts2-interceptor file verification

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, interceptor

I am using Struts2 and Apache POI jar. In my project I have to upload an Excel file and in my action I have to read this Excel file. For pre-action I am using Struts2 file upload interceptors. Everything is working perfectly except one thing. How to check whether the Excel file is empty or not using Struts2 interceptors? Is it possible to check whether the uploading file is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

1, In Interceptor itself you can call Customized class where you can check.

2, check file size while mention size in config file.

Comment: ok,but this not what i want,is there any interceptor parametr such as maximumSize . So what i actually want is that parameter like minSize in Struts2 intercptors

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the action where you upload the file:

```
 public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport
   { 
       File upload;
       //Other properties

       public String execute(){
        if (!fileValid()){
           return INPUT;
        }
        //Your stuff...
        return SUCCESS;
       }

       private boolean fileValid(){
          return upload != null;
          //You can do other checks here...
        }

   }
```

Comment: At least try to write consistent examples. You have variable named `upload` and inside `fileValid` method you are checking for `file`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I was in a hurry. You could edit my answer and correct my evident error.